# XmppFramework showing error

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, chat, xmppframework

I am creating chatting app in Objective-C using XMPPFramework,

I have installed XMPPFramework using pod... pods got installed successfully but when i build my app after install it shows me this error **Redefination of module dnssd**

I did some research but havn't found any thing related to this.

Here is my pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, ‘8.0’

target 'JabberClient' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!
   pod ‘XMPPFramework’

  # Pods for JabberClient

end
```

Please help me where i am making mistake?

***Thanks in advance !!***

Answer (score 0):

Try removing/commenting the `use_frameworks!` line.
It should be used if you're using Swift.

Comment: I am using objective-c i have mentioned in post

Comment: Yes. Uncomment the `use_frameworks` if you're using swift. 
So, comment out the `use_frameworks` if you're using objective-c.